# A faster way of proving that a 'theorem' (logic) is true.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose I want to prove that the following is a theorem.

$$\left [ \left ( P \vee Q \right ) \Rightarrow R \right ] \Rightarrow \left [ \left ( P \Rightarrow R \right ) \vee \left ( Q \Rightarrow R \right) \right ]$$

The most straightforward method would be to construct a truth table with $8$ rows, and then bash it out as you would with any other truth table.

However, this can get quite cumbersome and so the lecturer suggested a faster method. Intuitively, the method makes sense, but I am having trouble following what he is doing precisely.

The idea is as follows (paraphrasing):

> Assume the theorem is false, work backwards and obtain a contradiction or a counter-example.

Below is a screenshot of his notes.

[image]

I am guessing that the numbers represent the order in which we 'chase' the truth values backwards. So of course, we start with the implication connecting the left and right side, and assign it $F$. From here, I am unsure of what he is doing.

An explanation would really be great. But I am happy to receive the name of this technique or a link to another explanation.

Comment: What does the body of the question have to do with WFF?

Comment: You are correct. I have adjusted the title.

Comment: The logical law that underpins this is CCNpKqNqp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that:

> $[(P∨Q)⇒R]⇒[(P⇒R)∨(Q⇒R)]$

is *false*. This means:

> $(P∨Q)⇒R$ true and $(P⇒R)∨(Q⇒R)$ false.

Consider the disjunction; a disjunction is false when both disjuncts are; thus:

> $(P⇒R)$ false and $(Q⇒R)$ false.

Now, $P⇒R$ false needs $P$ true and $R$ false, while $Q⇒R$ false needs $Q$ true and $R$ false.

Up to now, we have: $P=Q=$**t** and $R=$**f**.

But the antecedent must be true and with $R=$**f** we are forced to have also: $P∨Q=$**f**, which implies $P=Q=$**f**.

Thus, $P$ and $Q$ must be both true and false: Contradiction !

Comment: Small note: presumably, the asker made a typo in the question, and the logical statement they actually meant was $\left [ \left ( P \vee Q \right ) \Rightarrow R \right ] \Rightarrow \left [ \left ( P \Rightarrow R \right ) \vee \left ( Q \Rightarrow R \right) \right ]$ (see also the teacher's note). The same technique works, though -- the analysis is just slightly longer, because in this case you actually have to consider the antecedent.

Comment: The logical law that underpins this is CCNpKqNqp.